# LibreOffice stopped working Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: libreoffice, crash

I just did a software update this morning, it went through without any issues, but then I discovered that LibreOffice stopped working completely. It was working fine yesterday and I had files open. After the update it crashed and would not come back. This is my work machine, so this is kind of a really big deal. I removed it completely using:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
```

I removed the `~/.config/libreoffice`. I reinstalled it (using the Ubuntu Software). Still no dice. Just sits there for a few moments blinking and the icon of whatever you picked, say Writer, goes away. No error message, nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you open a terminal window and enter `lowriter`, do you receive any error messages?  If so, please append your question with those errors.

Comment: Running `lowriter` at terminal has no effect, if libreoffice isn't declared at $PATH variable and was not installed by apt. As this computer is from OP workplace, it may be installed by dpkg tool.

Comment: @Redbob As the OP removed Libre using apt tools, I think it is a reasonable assumption that they also use apt to re-install.

Comment: No, I'm admin on the creature. I didn't use dpkg when I installed it the first time, I did it through Ubuntu Software. Keep wanting to call it an App Store. Bleh. 15 years of Mac (IRIX and Linux before that). I actually ended up fixing it just now. Installing it through Ubuntu Software is what appears to be broken. On a lark I installed LibreOffice with apt-get. It grabbed version 5.4 and it is working fine. I'm back in business. I think something's busted with that 5.3 installation. I'm going to go ahead and close this one.

Comment: FWIW - I use [https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to keep the fresh version of LO on my computer.  Please post what you have done as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Ubuntu Software, in  my opinion, is the last option to install software, because is not transparent as other kind of installation (apt, snapd, dpkg, synaptic.. ). It's really designed to newer users.

Comment: Yeah, that's the impression I've been getting. OS X was good for a while until they completely screwed it up. System upgrades started to cost me a week to recover from. I was using a Mac like I used my good old Onyx minicomputer. Went back to Linux this summer after I destroyed my MacPro by running OpenMPI on it. Fried it crispy. Couldn't handle the load. Got me an exotic laptop, a Titan Mobile Workstation and I'm not looking back. Now, how do I mark the question as "answered"? New to this forum, sorry.

Comment: Figured that out too. There's a button on the bottom. Duh. I need coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Tried installing from Ubuntu software and `apt-get install` but broken.

Remove LibreOffice completely.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
```

Remove the configuration files from:

```
~/.config/libreoffice
```

Download Fresh package

https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/

extract and install using

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Answer (score -1):

LibreOffice 5.3 is still broken and installing it through Ubuntu Software is broken too. I used `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`, just to see what would happen. It grabbed version 5.4, installed it and it's working fine. So if this happens to somebody else, just use apt-get to remove the thing, kill the `~/.config/libreoffice` directory and then install using apt-get. Don't bother with Ubuntu Software. 5.3 distribution has been on the fritz a bit for a few weeks. It lost my extensive font library from the menu. You could still get the fonts you wanted if you typed in a name, but in the drop-down box it would only show about a dozen standard system fonts. Yeah, I rebuilt the font cache and that didn't fix it. Anyways, if this happens to someone else, just get rid of 5.3 installation and install 5.4 and don't use Ubuntu Software to do that, use `apt-get` or `dpkg`, do the command-line thing. Oh, and 5.4 picked up all my fonts, everything. All back to normal.

Comment: You need to be clearly and more synthetic. Try to organize by paragraph and using code blocks.